# Adding Column into data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I want to add a column into my dataframe that identifies which group my data is from (in this case, year). What I have is:

```
Var1   Var2  Var3
X       X     X
X       X     X
X       X     X
```

What I want is:

```
Var1   Var2  Var3  Year
X       X     X   2018
X       X     X   2018
X       X     X   2018
```

I have created a matrix with the year information then used the cbind function. This could become taxing using with multiple datasets. Is there a better way? Thanks in advance. I have tried:

```
DF$year<-paste(rep("2018", 1:nrow))
```

and this did not work. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: R can recycle. You dont need to `rep`. You can just do `DF$year <- 2018`

Comment: Yep, this worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can just add the column as `df$Year <- 2018` like this:

```
# this is your data frame
df <- read.table(header =TRUE, text = "
  Var1   Var2  Var3
  X       X     X
  X       X     X
  X       X     X
")

# add a column
df$Year <- 2018
```

The result:

```
#> df
#   Var1 Var2 Var3 Year
# 1    X    X    X 2018
# 2    X    X    X 2018
# 3    X    X    X 2018
```

But it depends on your data.